# Удалить строку из таблицы

Tags: php, javascript, html

Из базы данных генерируется html-таблица с такими же полями. При нажатии на строку таблицы в javascript меняется её цвет (становится активной). А под таблицей есть кнопка удалить, которая должна удалять выделенную строку из html-таблицы, и БД (достаточно удалить из БД, а из html она удалится при регенерации).
Вопрос, как мне удалить выделенную строку? Ведь таблицу не обернёшь в form.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно так: около кнопки добавить скрытое поле

```
<input type="hidden" name="rowId" value="" id="rowId" />
```

При клике на строку таблицы обновлять value этого поля. Как-нибудь так, или отдельно вынести, неважно:

```
<tr id="1" onclick="document.getElementById('rowId').value = this.getAttribute('id')">
```

А при отправке формы смотреть это поле и удалять нужную строку в базе.

Comment: Благодарю. Так быстро отвечают на этом форуме. Что вас мотивирует?

Comment: В процессе ответа часто случается, что сам узнаешь что-то новое. Для самообучения =). Если ответ помог, отметьте галочкой ) Вариант C.Raf.T с использованием Ajax вообще, наверное, лучше, но это если Вы будете разбираться с этим Ajax. А дело стоящее, такие вещи без перезагрузки страницы смотрятся приянтее, конечно.

Comment: только один можно галочкой отметить?

Comment: вот честно говоря, не знаю. По идее да, один.

Comment: завтра проверю оба способа, и отмечу

Answer (score 2):

```js
$("tr").click(function() {
  let index = $(this).data("id")
  $.ajax({
    url: //link к базе данных на удаление
  })
  $(this).remove()
})
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr data-id="индекс в базе">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>aaa</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>bbb</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>ccc</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>ddd</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>eee</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: из базы нужно удалить, так я тоже могу

Comment: @Маша ))) а не понял вопроса...))

Comment: @Маша исправил.. как-то так..)

Comment: спасибо, завтра буду разбираться. А сейчас спать.